# Iterate over JSON Object using Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a JSON object and was wondering how I can iterate over the object to pull values for "id".

```
{
"totalSize": 5,
"done": true,
"records": [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "EventLogFile",
            "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT1U000003kk7dWAA"
        },
        "Id": "0AT1U000003kk7dWAA"
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "EventLogFile",
            "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT1U000003kk7eWAA"
        },
        "Id": "0AT1U000003kk7eWAA"
```

I was trying something below.

```
sub_data = s["records"]["id"]
for i in sub_data:
        print(sub_data['id'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the `records` key as a list and then access the `Id` key of each sub-dict:

```
for i in s["records"]:
    print(i['Id'])
```

Comment: Thanks!. I did try that and received following errorr:     for i in s["records"]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = """{ "totalSize": 5, 
        "done": true, "records": [ 
            { "attributes": { 
                "type": "EventLogFile", 
                "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT1U000003kk7dWAA" }, 
                "Id": "0AT1U000003kk7dWAA" } 
        ] 
    }"""
s = json.loads(s)

[r['Id'] for r in s['records']]

['0AT1U000003kk7dWAA']
```

Comment: Your solutions seem right. Just iterate over list of dictionary.Guess, I still  get the same error.    s1 = [r['id'] for r in s['records']]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @AshishLal can you add the JSON that triggers this error?

Comment: {
    "totalSize": 5,
    "done": true,
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "EventLogFile",
                "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/0AT1U000003kk7dWAA"
            },
            "Id": "0AT1U000003kk7dWAA"
        },
    ]
}

Comment: It works for me `[r['Id'] for r in s['records']]` the result is `['0AT1U000003kk7dWAA']`

Comment: I am sure it works. Not sure why its not working for me

Comment: @AshishLal Updated my answer, maybe that's the problem